# Is it possible to use the search function on stack exchange in the browser itself?

Tags: support, feature-request, search

On the top of my page, I have a search bar in math Stack Exchange:

[image]

Now, instead of google, is it possible to directly feed my search query into this search bar itself from the place you type address in of the browser?

Basically, this place:

[image]

Like, instead of 'google search' coming up here:

[image]

I want to have the Stack Exchange search thing, so I can search the question in stack exchange directly without first opening the Stack Exchange site and then searching for questions I want.

Comment: In Chrome, it is possible to [change default search engine](https://www.google.com/search?q=set+default+search+engine+chrome). (And probably in various other browsers, too.) Whether it would work for search on Stack Exchange or [math.se], I am not sure. (I am also not sure whether this is really on topic on this site - it seems more of a question about functionality of the browser you're using.)

Comment: BTW this post on [meta.se] is about something similar in Firefox: [Search stackoverflow (and serverfault) from firefox search box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27809).

Comment: Oh, got it, it was possible to change the engine in my settings ^^